# Delay loading Google Tag Manager and its consequences

Tags: google-tag-manager

After checking on PageSpeed Insights, the report stated that Google Tag Manager, along with tags that we added on to it (Facebook, Twitter and TikTok), is causing the website to have a high Total Blocking Time.

We tried to defer the loading of the GTM script, but it did not help too much with the Performance score on PageSpeed Insights. Then We thought to delay the loading of the GTM script two seconds after the DOM content has loaded, and also load GTM when the visitor makes an interaction with the website (click, scroll, tap, swipe). The latter solution works as our Performance score was in the high 90s.

The problem is that our SEO person opposes the solution. They say that delaying the loading of GTM will result in loss of data. When I ask them if they can provide which data are lost, they reply with whether I can prove that data are not lost.

Anyway, are they correct? The only data lost I can think of is when a visitor bounce before the two seconds are up without making any interactions.

Answer (score 1):

High total blocking time makes no sense unless you use GTM for rendering. GTM and third party pixels are non-blocking. Looks like the tool you use has issues checking what's blocking and what's not.

Both deferring and delaying GTM loads will lead to issues in the data. These are considered to be mistakes.

Your SEO person is correct about the data loss, but incorrect about asking you to prove the opposite. But it's not a surprise since SEO people are not exactly industry experts in analytics even though they're a very close data stakeholder.

You will lose pageviews and whatnot when users navigate off a page before the GTM script is fully loaded and executed. Losing those pageviews will be crucial when you lose the initial entry pageview because then GA will completely lose the original referrer, hence it will misattribute the traffic to the Direct channel whereas it must have been Organic or Paid.

The SEO data stakeholder is actually the third in the line to be worried about it. First being the Digital Analytics team, second - Marketing team.

There are other ways to lose data or rather having to needlessly increase the complexity of tracking when GTM is not loaded properly, but I'm not going to go there. Just use a better tool to assess page speed implications or debug how and why GTM is detected as a reason.

While it is indeed expedient to just defer a seemingly offending script, it's a very simplistic, junior move to make. Maybe try blocking GTM from loading, see if that improves the time to interactive. See if specific GTM listeners impact the lighthouse metrics. Make a version of the container that wouldn't have any time-based or element visibility-based triggers. See if that helps. Debug the issue deeper.